# Notation for inner product, vector

Tags: vectors

I want to convert the following continuous notation
$$ \min_u \int_\Omega \lambda(x) (u(x) - f(x))^2 \, dx \tag{1} $$

to a discrete version. Let me assume that $\lambda,u,f$ are vectorized with length $N$.

1. The following is not equivalent to (1), right?
   $$ \min_u \langle \lambda, (u-f)^2 \rangle \tag{2} $$
2. (3) is equivalent to (1), I think.
   $$ \min_u \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i (u_i-f_i)^2 \tag{3} $$

However, I want to denote the discrete version with vector form. How to elegantly denote?

---

I also want to convert the following:
$$ \int_\Omega \lambda(x) |\nabla u(x)| dx $$
where $u:\Omega\to\mathbb R^2$ and $|\nabla u(x)|=\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}$. It seems very complicated.

Comment: You're right about 1, $(u-f)^2$ isn't necessarily meaningful for vectors

Comment: One possibility is 
$$
\min_u (u - f)^T\operatorname{diag}(\lambda)(u - f)
$$
where 
$$
\operatorname{diag}(\lambda) = 
\pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ & & \lambda_N}
$$
this is the usual way that a quadratic form is presented.

Comment: It helps me a lot. I still have a problem. I added my question.

Comment: That's quite a bit tougher, I can't think of any generalized matrix/vector analog for this operation.